# How to get case insensitive tab-completion in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am using `HighLine::Question.readline` to achieve `tab completion` in Ruby. Below is the piece of code of `tab_complete.rb` which does that for me.

```
require "rubygems"
require "highline/import"

tab_complete = ["yes", "okay", "maybe", "no"]

selected = ask("Please say something: ", tab_complete) do |q|
  q.readline = true
end
p selected

-bash-4.1$ ruby tab_complete.rb
Please say something: yes
"yes"
```

The above code works fine for the items which are in the array, but I want to handle case-insensitive tab-completion. For example, if user enters `upcase` or `downcase` `y` and hit `tab` key it should get completes as `downcase` `yes` and that value should be saved in `selected`. Right now I get prompted to enter case-sensitive words as shown below:

```
-bash-4.1$ ruby tab_complete.rb
Please say something: Y
You must choose one of [yes, okay, maybe, no].
?  Please say something:
```

Any pointers on this will be really helpful to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

It’s open source btw.

Block argument of `ask` is an instance of `Highline::Question` that has [`case`](https://github.com/JEG2/highline/blob/bf489b632afd92c68df0b2c1f348afb66b5495aa/lib/highline/question.rb#L136) attribute. Here is [the example](https://github.com/JEG2/highline/blob/bf489b632afd92c68df0b2c1f348afb66b5495aa/examples/basic_usage.rb#L50) of usage:

```
selected = ask("What: ", tab_complete) do |q|
  q.case = :down # THIS
  q.readline = true
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and pointing to the example. I tried `q.case = :down` and it is setting `selected` value to downcase but it is not auto-completing when I hit `Y` followed by `tab` key. I was just thinking is it possible to do here?